# Static web site on S3 and CloudFront -- How to hide a non-prod version of the site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have static Reactjs site we developing, hosting on s3 with CloudFront, I'm wondering if it's possible to hide non-prod versions of a site under VPN access somehow, means dev. uat. qa. subdomains will be accessible only by users who is connected to VPC by VPN, my quick guess only way to do this it to setup VPC Endpoint and small EC2 based reverse-proxy with LB maybe for non prod envs.

If someone know how to do this without spinning up new instances - would be thanksfull.

Answer (score 0):

This is way I'll go, seems to be satisried all requirements above

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-using-cookies-protect-your-amazon-cloudfront-content-from-being-downloaded-by-unauthenticated-users/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security/